# Unable to build packages for whole project through script

Tags: shell, unix

I am working on continuos integration part(auto build).i am unable build all the pkgs it given script for all the pkgs.

```
selid1t601.xayybol.57> vi all_vobs1.sh
#!/bin/sh


VOBS=""

VOBS="bulkcm/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="ncms/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="cna/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="cnai/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="cnamb/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="gpi/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="cdmart/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="rah/src ${VOBS}"
VOBS="isp ${VOBS}"
VOBS="tckg ${VOBS}"
VOBS="prop/src ${VOBS}"

echo $VOBS
```

The above script contains vob of files required for package build.

if i comment few of them then package building is successful and i uncomment the commented vobs and comment the uncommented vobs then pkgs build is successful.

If i uncomment all of them then pkgs build is failing for some of the vobs which is not consistent

can you please suggest cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In continuous integration there can be dependencies which is present in between the files. You cannot just uncomment some of the the vobs and continue with the build, if you are uncommenting the vobs, then check for the dependencies of the respective files under the vob path. If you can resolve the dependencies, then you may get a proper build.